# .NET pie chart: how to add text to slices and rotate chart

Tags: c#, graphics, charts, rotation, pie-chart

The code below creates a 24 slice pie chart.  How do I:

1. Add text labels to each slice a la "Wheel of Fortune".
2. Rotate the pie chart? I want it to spin like "Wheel of Fortune".

   ```
   private void DrawPieChart()
   {
       Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
       g.Clear(this.BackColor);
       Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300);
       float angle = 0;
       Random random = new Random();
       int sectors = 24;
       int sweep = 360 / sectors;

        for(int i=0; i<24;i++)
       {
           Color clr = Color.FromArgb(random.Next(0, 255),random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255));
           g.FillPie(new SolidBrush(clr), rect, angle, sweep);
           angle += sweep;
       }
       g.Dispose();
   }
   ```

Comment: You don't need to escape HTML in code blocks.  (i<24)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what went wrong there.

Answer (score 2):

To add text labels, call `g.DrawString`.

**EDIT**: To make the textvertical like your image, rotate the Graphics object to `angle + sweep / 2`, and draw your text.  To make it draw downward,  yopu may be able to draw it in a small width and rely on character wrapping;  if that doesn't work, draw it character vy chaaracter and use `g.MeasureString` to figure out where to put the next character.

To rotate the entire chart, call `g.RotateTransform` with an angle in degrees before drawing it. **EDIT**: like this:

```
    private void DrawPieChart()
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        g.Clear(this.BackColor);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300);
        float angle = 0;
        Random random = new Random();
        int sectors = 24;
        int sweep = 360 / sectors;

         g.RotateTransform(90);        //Rotates by 90 degrees
         for(int i=0; i<24;i++)
        {
            Color clr = Color.FromArgb(random.Next(0, 255),random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255));
            g.FillPie(new SolidBrush(clr), rect, angle, sweep);
            angle += sweep;
        }
        g.Dispose();
    }
```

TO animate the rotation, make a field for the angle, increment it on a timer, and pass the field to `g.RotateTransform`.

Also, the correct way to draw things is to handle the control's `Paint` event, and draw using `e.Graphics`.  Then, when you want to redraw it, call `Invalidate`.  To prevent flickering, call `this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);` in the constructor.